# REGEX REPLACE errors trying to configure a project

Tags: cmake

I am trying to build [Ogre-next](https://ogrecave.github.io/ogre-next/api/2.3/_setting_up_ogre_windows.html). But when I try to configure the Cmake I get these two regex errors on repeat :

```
CMake Error at OgreMain/CMakeLists.txt:495 (string):
  string does not recognize sub-command REGEX REPLACE


CMake Error at OgreMain/CMakeLists.txt:496 (string):
  string sub-command REGEX, mode MATCH needs at least 5 arguments total to
  command.
```

The code that generate those errors is the following:

```
# install OgreMain
ogre_config_lib(OgreMain TRUE)
foreach(HEADER_FILE ${HEADER_FILES})
    string(REGEX REPLACE "((${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}|${OGRE_BINARY_DIR})/)?(include|src)/" "" RELATIVE_HEADER_FILE ${HEADER_FILE})
    string(REGEX MATCH "((.*)/)+" HEADER_SUBDIRECTORY ${RELATIVE_HEADER_FILE})
    install(FILES ${HEADER_FILE} DESTINATION include/OGRE/${HEADER_SUBDIRECTORY})
endforeach()
```

There is an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21044744/7862279) that could help me but I don't know anything about cmake so I don't know how to implement the solution...

> You can output the variables and check which one is empty and should not be empty. [...]
> If you want to force your regex, you can make quotation marks around the arguments.

How do I output the missing links or what do I quote exactly to ignore the errors "properly" (even though I'd prefer to not ignore and fix the errors)?

*I am on Windows and with Cmake `3.20.2`*

Comment: What is your cmake verison? Is it too old?

Comment: @KamilCuk it is `3.20.0`

Comment: Weird. The OGRE-next [has](https://github.com/OGRECave/ogre-next/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.0)` at the top, but even 2.8.0 version of CMake [supports](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.0/cmake.html#command:string) `string(REGEX REPLACE)` command flow.

Comment: Are you sure the `HEADER_FILES` variable does not contain empty strings as element? You could check by using the `--trace-expand` option, but beware that the output gets very long so you'll need to redirect stdout and stderr to a file to properly inspect everything since the console probably won't allow you to scroll up even half way though the output. (Not sure btw why they did not use `foreach(IN LISTS)` there...)

Comment: Just realized that you're not going with a stable version. Try upgrading to 3.20.2. Maybe there were some bugs that made into version 3.20.0...

Comment: @fabian I don't have any HEADER_FILES variable displayed in the Cmake gui so I am not sure what you are asking me to check... But I saw some set and append functions on the `HEADER_FILES` variable in the `CmakeLists.txt` file so I'm guessing the variable isn't empty. I also update to `3.20.2` and I still have the problem